# display product name and product image on custom page at admin grid

Tags: magento2, product, grid, admin-panel

I want to display the product name and product image in the custom page at admin grid

[image: in this on view click one custom page open]
[image: in this page I want to display the product name and image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
   <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_confi guration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" 
 xsi:type="string">magneto_product_product_form.product_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">magneto_product_product_form.product_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">General Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">magneto_product_product_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        <!-- <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">Magneto\PopupQuestion\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\BackButton</item>
            <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">Magneto\PopupQuestion\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\DeleteButton</item>
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Magneto\PopupQuestion\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\SaveButton</item>
            <item name="save_and_continue" xsi:type="string">Magneto\PopupQuestion\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\SaveAndContinueButton</item>
        </item> -->
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="product_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magneto\PopupQuestion\Model\PopupQuestion\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">product_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">product_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" path="*/*/save" xsi:type="url"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="General">

        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="customization_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Name</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Product</item>
                    <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customization_name</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="customization_email">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Email</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Product</item>
                    <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customization_email</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="customization_message">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Message</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Product</item>
                    <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customization_message</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="customization_attachment" class="Magneto\PopupQuestion\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Thumbnail">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                     <!-- <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">file</item> -->
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Attachment</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Product</item>
                    <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customization_attachment</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/thumbnail</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

    </fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: Please give descriptive question...

Comment: i have added my code